Setting up Selenium feature tests with Github Actions
I'm trying to setup Github Actions to run my feature specs using Rails and Selenium. I tried a couple different things and the farthest I got was following the steps in this question/answer
But I keep running into a connection error:
Connection refused - connect(2) for "172.17.0.1" port 80
Below is my github_action_ci.yml file:
name: "Ruby on Rails CI"
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]
jobs:
  run-rspec-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:12
        ports:
          - "5433:5432"
        options: >-
            --health-cmd pg_isready
            --health-interval 10s
            --health-timeout 5s
            --health-retries 5
        env:
          POSTGRES_DB: db_test
          POSTGRES_USER: username
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
        browser:
        image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug

        ports:
          - "5900:5900" #for VNC access
          - "4444:4444" #for webdriver access
    env:
      RAILS_ENV: test
      DATABASE_URL: "postgres://username:password@localhost:5433/db_test"
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Set Hostname Env Var
        run: |
          echo "SERVER_HOSTNAME=$(docker network inspect bridge --format='{{(index .IPAM.Config 0).Gateway}}')" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
      - name: Install Ruby and gems
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          bundler-cache: true
      - name: Set up database schema
        run: |
          bin/rails db:schema:load
      - name: Run specs
        run: |
          bundle exec rspec

and here's my spec/support/capybara.rb file
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'

if ENV["CI"]
  Capybara.register_driver :remote_chrome do |app|
    options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
                                   browser: :remote,
                                   url: "http://#{ENV['SERVER_HOSTNAME']}:#{ENV['SERVER_PORT']}",
                                   options:)
  end

  Capybara.configure do |config|
    config.run_server = true
    config.javascript_driver = :remote_chrome
    config.app_host = "http://#{ENV['SERVER_HOSTNAME']}:#{ENV['SERVER_PORT']}"
    config.server_host = '0.0.0.0'
    config.server_port = ENV['SERVER_PORT']
    config.always_include_port = true
    config.default_max_wait_time = 4
  end
else
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome
end

Any help would be much appreciated!
